# Salvar imagem vindo da API na memória do celular

Tags: android, imagem, exceção

Estou tentando salvar uma imagem vindo da API na memória do celular.

```
    public void saveSkin() {
    ivSkinSaver.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bm = ivSkinSaver.getDrawingCache();

    OutputStream Out = null;
    try {
        File mediaFile;
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Android/data"
                + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                + "/Files");
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy_HH:mm_").format(new Date());
        String mImageName = timeStamp + stringSkin;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);
        mediaFile.createNewFile();
        Out = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"file saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later." + e.getStackTrace(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, Out);
        Out.flush();
        Out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
}
```

Eu usei o `e.printStackTrace()` e o resultado é : "java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

Comment: Talvez porque você não tem permissão mesmo. Verifique seu Manifest se concedeu permissão de escrita no device: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Além disso, se você tiver usando Android 6.0 tem que conceder permissão em tempo de execução.

Comment: Ja coloquei o WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE e READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE mas continua com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Em que versão do Android está a executar a aplicação?

Comment: @ramaral está na versão 6.0

Comment: @WellingtonYogui  a resposta abaixo te atendeu ou precisa de mais alguma informação?!

Answer (score 3):

Isso pode estar ocorrendo porque você de alguma forma não concedeu permissão de escrita no dispositivo. Veja como deve está seu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    ...
    <application>
        ...
        <activity> 
            ...
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Além disso, deve observar também se o uso da aplicação é no Android 6.0 + , deve conceder permissão em tempo de execução. Veja como fazer uma [solicitação de permissões em tempo de execução](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=pt-br) na própria documentação.

A partir do Android Marshmallow, API 23, os usuários concedem permissões a aplicativos enquanto eles estão em execução, não quando eles são instalados.

> Essa abordagem otimiza o processo de instalação de aplicativos, pois o
>   usuário não precisa conceder permissões ao instalar ou atualizar o
>   aplicativo.

Além desta questão, também estabelece ao usuário mais controle sobre os recursos do aplicativo. Por exemplo, um usuário poderia optar por permitir que um aplicativo de câmera tenha acesso à câmera, mas não à localização do dispositivo. O usuário pode revogar as permissões a qualquer momento na tela de configurações da aplicação.

Veja um exemplo:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

      // Verifica se já mostramos o alerta e o usuário negou na 1ª vez.
      if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(context,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
           // caso o usuário tenha negado a permissão anteriormente, e não tenha marcado o check "nunca mais mostre este alerta"

      } else {
          // solicita permissão
          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},0);
      }
} else {
     // caiu aqui está tudo ok
}
```

Comment: Ja tenho um método que faz essa validação, mas msm assim cai no catch na hora de salvar.

Comment: Como apareceu "Permission denied", a principal fator a considerar é a questão de permissão de leitura e escrita. Talvez seja seu algoritmo para salvar o arquivo então. Você pegar a imagem de uma URL para salvar no dispositivo certo?

Comment: Sim, eu recebo o link da imagem pela api e passo para uma imagemView e coloquei um botão para salvar a imagem.